# location.reload(forceGet) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

We have `location.reload()` in JavaScript. In its default behaviour, `forceGet` will set to 'false'. So it reloads the current page from the cache. What will be the behaviour if **cache is off** or person is **browsing from private window**?

Answer (score 0):

> Chrome and Firefox will always perform a round-trip to the server,
>   asking for the current resource, no matter what parameter you pass to
>   .reload().

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053293/2026606